# Tkinter: How to insert text into text widget that's part of a Frame?

Tags: python, tkinter

I need help inserting text in a `Text` widget that's part of a `Frame`.

```
class Test_frame(Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.config(width = 700, height = 450)
        self.logs_frame = LabelFrame(self, height = 402, width = 348, text = 'Logs')
        self.logs_frame.grid(column = 1, row = 0, pady=10, sticky = N)
        self.logs_frame.grid_propagate(0)

        self.text_box = Text(self.logs_frame, width=40, pady=10, height=22)
        self.text_box.pack(side="left")

        self.scroll_y = Scrollbar(self.logs_frame, orient="vertical", command=self.text_box.yview)
        self.scroll_y.pack(side="left", expand=True, fill="y")
        self.text_box.configure(yscrollcommand=self.scroll_y.set)

        self.text_box.insert (?????.END, "Sample Text")
```

I have no idea how to access that `Text` widget now.

`Test_frame` is part of a `Notebook`:

```
class App(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        self.my_notebook = ttk.Notebook(self)
        self.my_notebook.pack(pady = 5)
        self.frames = {}
        for F in (Test_frame, Final_flash_frame):
            frame = F()
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.pack(fill = 'both', expand = 1)
        self.my_notebook.add(self.frames[Test_frame], text = "Testing")
```

Comment: (To complete your example, you should include your import lines and the startup code that creates the app and instantiates the frame and runs the loop.  So people can test the code themselves) The test frame object should provide access to the text box.

Comment: @RufusVS - The code is pretty big and I'm not sure exactly what part of the code is needed to have only this part running. Sorry, I've told you I'm not the best at this.

Answer (score 1):

I created a minimal source, but I guess you solved your problem.

I added a little button to add text, and added some text from outside the class.

Here it is, anyway:

```
import tkinter as Tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from tkinter import *

def BumpText(textbox):
    textbox.insert(END,", MORE TEXT")


class Test_frame(Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.config(width = 700, height = 450)
        self.logs_frame = LabelFrame(self, height = 402, width = 348, text = 'Logs')
        self.logs_frame.grid(column = 1, row = 0, pady=10, sticky = N)
        self.logs_frame.grid_propagate(0)

        self.text_box = Text(self.logs_frame, width=40, pady=10, height=22)
        self.text_box.pack(side="left")

        self.scroll_y = Scrollbar(self.logs_frame, orient="vertical", command=self.text_box.yview)
        self.scroll_y.pack(side="left", expand=True, fill="y")
        self.text_box.configure(yscrollcommand=self.scroll_y.set)

        self.text_box.insert(END, "Sample Text")

        self.button = Button(self.logs_frame, text="Add\nText", command=lambda:self.text_box.insert(END, ", More Text"))
        self.button.pack(side="bottom")

class App(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        self.my_notebook = ttk.Notebook(self)
        self.my_notebook.pack(pady = 5)
        self.frames = {}
        for F in (Test_frame,):  # , Final_flash_frame):
            frame = F()
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.pack(fill = 'both', expand = 1)
        self.my_notebook.add(self.frames[Test_frame], text = "Testing")

        for F,f in self.frames.items():
            try:
                f.text_box.insert(END," (Added by App)")
            except Exception as e:
                pass  # ignore frames without text_box 


if __name__ == "__main__":
    App().mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so apparently just using:

```
self.text_box.insert (END, "Sample Text")
```

works

Cheers,
A